# how get messages from activemq dlq?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to write a script that pulls messages from activeMQ queue and purge them after. I tried looking it up online but couldn't find any examples to teach me how to do it. I'm want to know how can I connect to DLQ and how can I purge it? 
Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

DLQ is like any topic or queue and you can subscribe to it like any topic or queue and consume messages accumulated. Here is the list [http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html][1]

The name of the DLQ to subscribe to it is `ActiveMQ.DLQ` if you not have an `individualDeadLetterStrategy` , you subscribe and do your business onMessage method . 
[http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html][2]

New Advisories in 5.4 `ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageDLQd.*` accessible by `org.apache.activemq.advisory.AdvisorySupport.getMessageDLQdAdvisoryTopic(ActiveMQDestination);`